# heroku scheduling clock.js example

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduling

I am trying to define a worker process in Heroku for my web app, but not able to find how to schedule invocation of this worker.file via clock.js cron expression. 
I am following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes
Please share any example of clock.js which I can use to write cron expression to invoke my worker process.

Comment: I created an example to answer an similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26285974/1290781